# SIP Customer Devices under NAT

Tags: asterisk, sip, rtp, pbx

I have a question about RTP and SIP Ports.

Actually I have this configuration Asterisk PBX -> Routerboard with NAT -> 3 SIP Customer Devices.

To make them work correctly I forced a different port for each of them (one is 5060, the other 5061, and the third 5062)

Now I have also to force different RTP port for each of them? (ex. 5004, 5005 and 5006)

Thank you in advice

Answer (score 0):

Actually it should be range of ports, not one. RTP ports are configured on your SIP customer Devices, check manual for that device for more details. For X-lite softphone it is under Account Settings -> Topology -> Port Ranges.

Comment: Yes for all my devices is a range, but on Grandstream GXP1620 it let me to give only one port, in this case I have to give different port to each grandstream?

Thank you again

Comment: I don't know about Grandstream, but it looks strange.

Answer (score 0):

On the Asterisk PBX side, you want to set your range from from 10000 to 20000.

EG:

## rtp.conf

```
;
; RTP Configuration
;
[general]
;
; RTP start and RTP end configure start and end addresses
;
rtpstart=10000
rtpend=20000
```

This regulates what ports that Asterisk will -*accept*- and -*transmit*- RTP traffic from on it's side.  (per http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+config+rtp.conf).

The Grandstream phones allow you to set an RTP port that they will transmit -*from*- so that you can restrict your firewall for RTP outgoing.  You can have multiple Grandstream SIP phones all with the same RTP port defined.  Since each one has it's own NAT'd address, the firewall will keep them all seperate, regardless of what ports you assign them.

When the SIP call is negotiated, the PBX and the Phone will chat back and forth and establish what ports that the RTP stream should be sent to.  You don't have to worry about that.